# How to run application from terminal without knowing name?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I have installed the package "***doublecmd-common***" as it exists in the repository. Then I tried to run it, but I got the message: `There is no application with this name`. Then I tried to run `doublecmd` and it works okay, but it was just a lucky guess.

How can I find out the name of the package after I install it? I tried `apt-cache search`, but what if I don't know full name of the package? There are only empty lines there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the name of the package that was installed. I would then list all the files from the package:

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

The files that are in bin directory are the ones that you can run. To be able to scroll through list type

```
dkpg -L <package name> | less
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: with package "doublecmd-common" I also have installed package "doublecmd-help-ru", but it's not contains in bin directory at all. What I should do? By the way, when i use "dpkg -L <package name>" I see many path's and I can not scroll back the screen.

Comment: "doublecmd-help-ru" is the package that consists only of help files. I have edited the answer to add info how to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

"Long" file list, `doublecmd-help-ru` http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/all/doublecmd-help-ru/filelist

Use the on-line file list or run `dpkg -L doublecmd-help-ru | less`

On-line search http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/doublecmd-help-ru : Any package name (or part of name) can be entered into 'Search'.